# Why does this code cause the program to stop working?

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error

When you run this, the line with the error comment causes the program to stop working, at least for me. It's such simple code, I am sort of baffled as to why this would cause things to break?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

static const int ARRAY_SIZE = 100;

bool runAgain ( ) {
    char runChar;

    cout << "\n\nRun again? (Y/N)";
    cin >> runChar;
    runChar = toupper(runChar);
    if(runChar != 'Y')
        return false;

    system("cls");
    return true;
}

int main ( ) {

   int nums[ARRAY_SIZE];
   int length;
   int num, highIndex, lowIndex;

   length = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(int);
   srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); //make numbers more random

   do {

      cout << "Array contains: \n";

      for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         num = rand() % 1000 + 1;

         if(i == 0)
             highIndex, lowIndex = i;
         else if(num > nums[highIndex]) //@@ ERROR occurs on this line
             highIndex = i;
         else if(num < nums[lowIndex])
             lowIndex = i;

         nums[i] = num;

         cout << num << "\n";
      }

      cout << "\nHighest Value: " << nums[highIndex] << " at index " << highIndex;
      cout << "\nLowest Value: " << nums[lowIndex] << " at index " << lowIndex;

   }while(runAgain());

   return 0;
}
```

The error is specifically that windows says that .cpp has stopped working and ends the run superficially. From running a debugger, I know it happens after the first iteration of the loop during the first else if in the for loop.

edit: ahh, yes the issue was the 'highIndex, lowIndex = i'. Thanks for the help

Comment: As an aside, consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and C++ [random number generators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Also, why not just do `int length = ARRAY_SIZE;`?

Comment: It's not necessary to edit your question with thanks. Instead, If an answer was useful to you (the most useful answer) you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `highIndex, lowIndex = i;`.

This does not, as you think, assign `highIndex` and `lowIndex` the value of `i`. Only `lowIndex` is assigned, `highIndex` remains uninitialised. Therefore the program crashes when you try to dereference the array using `highIndex` as the value could be anything.

Change your code line to:

```
highIndex = lowIndex = i;
```